# Requesting more than one oauth2 scope through AccountManager in Android

Tags: android, api, authentication, oauth

I'm in a situation where I need to request access tokens for two scopes (from my android application), `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.userinfo`

I would like to get both permissions on a single call to `getAuthToken`, but can't figure out the string to pass in the `authTokenType` parameter. I tried several reasonable combinations with no positive results :(

Has anyone solved this issue? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need multiple OAuth 2.0 scopes, [use a space-separated list](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Android).

```
oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.userinfo
```

You asked for sample code, so have a look at the [Google Docs Upload Sample](https://github.com/mendhak/googledocs-upload-sample) application, and in this application have look at the authentication flow done in [this sample Android screen](https://github.com/mendhak/googledocs-upload-sample/blob/master/src/com/mendhak/example/PureJavaUploadActivity.java) (ignore that it's about Google Docs, it still authorizes first).  You can get the whole application and run it in an emulator with Google APIs present or run it on your phone.  The authorization workflow starts with the buttonAuthorize click, Authorize() and you are specifically interested in this method:

```
private void gotAccount(Account account)
{

    Bundle options = new Bundle();

    accountManager.getAuthToken(
            account,                     // Account retrieved using getAccountsByType()
            "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.userinfo",            // Auth scope
            //"writely",            // Auth scope, doesn't work :(
            options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
            this,                           // Your activity
            new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
            null);    // Callback called if an error occurs
}
```

The user gets this access request screen:

[image]

Note that this is using the 'local' OAuth2 mechanism, not opening a web browser, but using the authentication provided when you first activated the Android phone.

Also note that the user sees the full URL of the scope instead of a friendly name, I [haven't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654633/where-is-the-android-authorization-token-type-alias-list-for-google-apis) found a way around this and if you do find out it would be great if you could share the answer.

Comment: I already tried that with no success :(, have you used this before? If so, can you provide a small code snippet showing how? Thanks!!

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a reference to a sample, try it out.

Comment: I tried again, with no success... Almost copied the entire source, but there must be something else... This feels like the correct direction though, thanks!

Comment: What exactly is happening - do you get the Allow/Deny screen above, or an error?

Comment: I get one screen exactly like the one above, and after that another prompt appears saying there's something wrong with my account, and prompts to enter my password...

Comment: Taking a guess here: have you filled in the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET in [OAuth2Client.java](https://github.com/mendhak/googledocs-upload-sample/blob/master/src/com/mendhak/example/OAuth2Client.java)?

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same issue. Shah is almost right, but his scope string is wrong. It should be

```
"oauth2:<scope_url> <scope_url>"
```

not

```
"oauth2:<scope_url> oauth2:<scope_url>"
```